# Meteor.user() doesn’t contain emails field

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am using account-google, I don't know why it doesn't publish emails to the client.

From the doc about Meteor.user():

> By default the server publishes username, emails, and profile (writable by user).

I only get

```
Object { _id: "vK5ddWtypCewCwbSL", profile: Object }
```

on my client after running Meteor.user(), but I want to use Meteor.user().emails, anything I missed here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you removed auto publish module, then you need to manually publish user collection.**

If you are using server side publish method, then you will not get email field until you publish that field from server.

use following code at server side.

```
Meteor.publish("user",function(){
  return Meteor.users.find(this.userId,{
    fields:{
        "services.google.accessToken":0,
        "services.google.expiresAt":0,
        "services.google.idToken":0,
        "services.resume":0
    }
  });
});
```

This method will allow you to access email field at client side.

Comment: why do i have to manually publish it? hasn't the doc mentioned emails is published by default?

Comment: I made this working by also subscribe it from a Tracker.autorun(), I still don't understand why I need to put this into Tracker.autorun()

Comment: @Sawyer If you removed auto publish package, then automatic publishing for user collection will also removed, so you need to publish that collection manually.

Comment: The _.id, profile, and possibly email for users created through the username/password system is published. For users created through Google/Facebook OAUTH, emails are not published.

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny:  In order to get the emails[0].address field for users created through Google/Facebook OAUTH where should I subscribe the users collection